# Basic usage of LLVM with CLANG on Windows

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I need some help in using LLVM

1) I am downloading CLANG and LLVM from here http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.6.0

2) I am compiling CLANG and LLVM

3) I am following steps from  http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html#an-example-using-the-llvm-tool-chain

`clang -c hello.c -emit-llvm -o hello.bc`   - generates hello.bc

`lli hello.bc` -  fails with this error

```
LLVM ERROR: Incompatible object format!
Stack dump:
0.      Program arguments: lli.exe hello.bc
```

I am doing this from Windows. Can someone help ?

Comment: Probably you don't want to emit LLVM bitcode but generate directly an executable as described at the link you shared.

Comment: I do want to emit bitecode and interpret (lli.exe) the bitecode. A second option is to compile bitecode (llc) to .exe but it seems that only genereates .asm

Comment: It's a homework, so i need to get trough bitecode

Answer (score 0):

c is compile into EOF format that is not compatible with Windows
Follow code helped me get through the bitecode

```
lli -mtriple=i686-pc-windows-cpu-elf hello.bc
```